# Button not appearing correctly on Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-button

I have a Button set up like this:

```
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Send" 
        android:padding="-5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="-10dp"
    android:background="@color/red"/>
```

Here is how it looks like in Android 4.0 and above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBvrw.png

Here is how it looks like in Android 2.3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hoxs7.png

As you can see, the 2.3 button seems squished together and very small. How can I fix this so new versions and 2.3 atleast have same resemblance?

Comment: I think this is due to the size of your image.

Comment: I Think this due to version wise Button default size

Answer (score 1):

It's about the device size, create multiple `values` folder(`values`, `values-sw600dp`, `values-v11` etc) make each of them has `dimens.xml`. In `dimens.xml` define different padding values. Then in your layout file use this values instead of hardcoded ones. 
e.g

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Send" 
    android:padding="@dimens/padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimens/paddingBottom"
    android:background="@color/red"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain the different values folders for me? Which devices use the values-sw600dp, values-v11, etc? Thanks

Comment: sw600dp means the devices with minimum 600dp width will use this folder, you can change the value of course and sw=smallest width, also you can make it w600dp which means exactly the 600dp devices will use it. and for v11 it means the devices with API level 11 will use it, you can also change this too

Answer (score 1):

Use positive values for padding, set `textColor` attribute for white color:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Send"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Moreover, use [android-holo-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate a proper styles, selectors, drawables for `Button` for all APIs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a two ways to solve this problem..

1: need to put padding all side.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Send" 
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

2: need to give fixed size for this button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Send"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Both are easy and perfect lookup.